# "ip rule" iproute2 save/restore script?

Tags: networking

I am using a bit advanced network configuration with multiple routing tables. I configure these initially using `ip rule add from $interface table rtable_$interface` commands.
I can save these rules into a file using `ip rules save > ip-rules.cfg` and restore them using `ip rule restore < ip-rules.cfg`.

I know of the `iptables-persistent` package that provides a convenient solution for saving and restoring iptables configurations. This will unfortunately not work for me.

I can't seem to find the equivalent for **iproute2**, i.e. "ip rule". Do i have to make my own?

PS: I am on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS - perhaps a script like that was added in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS or Ubuntu 22.04 LTS? Pointers welcome.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't see how it is relevant but what if i want to save/restore the effect of commands such as "ip rule add from ens5 table rt5"?
"